# ToLookup - create lookup where "bucket" can be indexed

Tags: c#, linq, lookup

If I have

```
record R(string Name, int Id);

var rList = new List<R>()
{
    new R("Fred", 2),
    new R("Fred", 3),
    new R("Fred", 4),
    new R("Jim", 10),
};
```

is it possible to create a lookup where each bucket can be indexed?

For example:

```
var lk = rList.ToLookup(r => r.Name);

var fred1 = lk["Fred"][0];
var fred2 = lk["Fred"][1];

var harryCount = lk["Harry"].Count();
```

I don't want to use a `Dictionary` as `lk["Harry"]` will throw.

Thanks

Comment: Just write your own class that does that? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by bucket. Do you mean a grouping of values with the same key? I also do not see what the problem is. Have you tried this yet? Your question gives me the idea that you haven't even tried to find out. lookup[] returns an IEnumerable which you can't apply indexing on, so short answer. No you can't in this exact way

Comment: You might want to consider using `ElementAt` instead of the index. I *think* under the hood it's implemented with a list implementation, so that would still be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet:

```
ILookup<string, R> lk = people.ToLookup(t => t.Name);
var freds = lk["Fred"].ToList();
var fred1 = freds[0];
var fred2 = freds[1];

var harryCount = lk["Harry"].Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the second indexer, you could use the [`ElementAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat) LINQ operator:

```
var lk = rList.ToLookup(r => r.Name);

var fred1 = lk["Fred"].ElementAt(0);
var fred2 = lk["Fred"].ElementAt(1);
```

The internal .NET class that implements the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface, also implements the `IList<TElement>` interface ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Grouping.cs#L50)). Furthermore, the `ElementAt` operator includes optimizations for enumerable sequences that implement the `IList<T>` interface ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ElementAt.cs#L12)), reducing the computational complexity of the operation from O(n) to O(1):

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)
{
    /* ... */
    else if (source is IList<TSource> list)
    {
        return list[index];
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

So in this particular case you can use the `ElementAt` with clear conscience.

Comment: Alternatively cast to `IList<TSource>` directly

Comment: @Charlieface that would be risky. A future .NET release could replace the internal `IGrouping<K,E>` implementation with a type that doesn't implement the `IList<T>` interface. Instead it could implement some other internal interface, for the purpose of preserving the performance optimizations. It's not likely to happen, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @TheodorZoulias, `Grouping` implements `IList<T>` although it's undocumented.

So you can just cast it

```cs
var lk = rList.ToLookup(r => r.Name);

var fred1 = ((IList<R>)lk["Fred"])[0];
var fred2 = ((IList<R>)lk["Fred"])[1];

var harryCount = ((IList<R>)lk["Harry"]).Count();
```